# How to remove line break after span style="float: right"

Tags: css-float, html, line-breaks

I need to display 3 blocks of text in a td, 1st block to the left, 2nd to the center and 3rd to the right with no line break, so it will display

1st block                                    2nd block                                     3rd block

i tried

```
<td>
    <span style="float: left; display:inline-block;">1st block </span>
    <span style="float: center; display:inline-block;">2ndblock </span>
    <span style="float: right; display:inline-block;">3rd block </span>
</td>
```

it seems float will cause line break, even when inline-block is used.

please help. thank you very much.

Comment: I cannot seem to replicate this unless each span tag's width is set to 100%.  Do you have additional CSS attached to this piece?

Comment: Try putting all the span's on the same line in the code.

Comment: put all the span in the same line isn't an option for me, but you might be right about the CSS because the table is using some customized css class. and i figured i can just create a new table to do the spacing.  thank you for your help, Jay.